# bootstrap carousel active indicator onclick doesn't pause

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3, carousel

I am using bootstrap carousel, I adjusted the functionality for it to work with hover

The Problem: When I CLICK on any of the circle images it scroll to the next one

Expected behaviour: It should stay on the current slide (pause)

what is the function I should use to change this onclick behaviour

**Live version here:**
http://designs.josephr.mobi/test/

```js
$('.carousel').carousel({
  interval: 299999
})
$(".carousel").click(function(){
  $('.carousel').carousel('pause');
});
```

```css
html, body {padding:0; margin:0; width:100%;}
.carousel-inner > .item {
    -webkit-transition: 0.1s ease-in-out left ;
    -moz-transition: 0.1s ease-in-out left ;
    -o-transition: 0.1s ease-in-out left ;
    transition: 0.1s ease-in-out left ;
}
#quote-carousel {
    padding: 0 10px 30px 10px;
    margin-top: 30px;
}
#quote-carousel .carousel-control {
    background: none;
    color: #CACACA;
    font-size: 2.3em;
 font-family: Gotham, "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
    text-shadow: none;
    margin-top: 30px;
}
#quote-carousel .carousel-control.left {
    left: -60px;
}
#quote-carousel .carousel-control.right {
    right: -60px;
}
#quote-carousel .carousel-indicators {
    right: 50%;
    top: auto;
    bottom: 0px;
    margin-right: -19px;
 position:relative !important;
}
#quote-carousel .carousel-indicators li {
    width: 128px;
    height: 128px;
    margin: 5px;
    cursor: pointer;
    border-radius: 50px;
    opacity: 0.4;
    overflow: hidden;
    transition: all 0.1s;
}
#quote-carousel .carousel-indicators li.active {
    background: white;
    border-radius: 100px;
    opacity: 1;
    overflow: hidden;
 border:3px solid #FFBC00;
}
#quote-carousel .carousel-indicators li.active img {
 cursor:default;
}
#quote-carousel .carousel-indicators li img {
 cursor:default;
}
.carousel-inner {
    min-height: 240px;
}
.item blockquote {
    border-left: none;
    margin: 0;
}
.item blockquote p:before {
    content: "\f10d";
    font-family: 'Fontawesome';
    float: left;
    margin-right: 10px;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 991px) {
 #quote-carousel .carousel-indicators li { width:92px; height:92px; }
 .carousel-inner {  min-height: 240px; }
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 401px) {
 #quote-carousel .carousel-indicators li { width:72px; height:72px; }
 .carousel-inner {  min-height: 240px; }
}
```

```html
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="robots" content="noindex">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title>Carousel with face indicators</title>

    <link href="https://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" id="bootstrap-css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.6.3/css/font-awesome.min.css">


</head>
<body>
 

<div class="container-fluid" id="cr">
<div class="row">

                    <div class="col-md-12" data-wow-delay="0.01s">
                        <div class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel" id="quote-carousel">

                            <!-- Carousel Slides / Quotes -->
                            <div class="carousel-inner text-center">

                                <!-- Quote 1 -->
                                <div class="item active">
                                    <blockquote>
                                        <div class="row">
                                            <div class="col-sm-8 col-sm-offset-2">
            <!-- Quote 1 test -->
                                                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur.</p>
                                                <small>perseon name 1</small>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    </blockquote>
                                </div>

                                <!-- Quote 2 -->
                                <div class="item">
                                    <blockquote>
                                        <div class="row">
                                            <div class="col-sm-8 col-sm-offset-2">
            <!-- Quote 2 test -->
                                                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur.</p>
                                                <small>perseon name 2</small>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    </blockquote>
                                </div>

                                <!-- Quote 3 -->
                                <div class="item">
                                    <blockquote>
                                        <div class="row">
                                            <div class="col-sm-8 col-sm-offset-2">
            <!-- Quote 3 test -->
                                                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur.</p>
                                                <small>perseon name 3</small>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    </blockquote>
                                </div>

                                <!-- Quote 4 -->
                                <div class="item">
                                    <blockquote>
                                        <div class="row">
                                            <div class="col-sm-8 col-sm-offset-2">
            <!-- Quote 4 test -->
                                                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur.</p>
                                                <small>perseon name 4</small>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    </blockquote>
                                </div>

                                <!-- Quote 5 -->
                                <div class="item">
                                    <blockquote>
                                        <div class="row">
                                            <div class="col-sm-8 col-sm-offset-2">
            <!-- Quote 5 test -->
                                                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur.</p>
                                                <small>perseon name 5</small>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    </blockquote>
                                </div>

                                <!-- Quote 6 -->
                                <div class="item">
                                    <blockquote>
                                        <div class="row">
                                            <div class="col-sm-8 col-sm-offset-2">
            <!-- Quote 6 test -->
                                                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur.</p>
                                                <small>perseon name 6</small>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    </blockquote>
                                </div>
                                
                                <!-- Quote 7 -->
                                <div class="item">
                                    <blockquote>
                                        <div class="row">
                                            <div class="col-sm-8 col-sm-offset-2">
            <!-- Quote 7 test -->
                                                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur.</p>
                                                <small>perseon name 7</small>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    </blockquote>
                                </div>
                                
                            </div>
                            
                            
                            <!-- Bottom Carousel Images -->
                            <ol class="carousel-indicators">
                                <!-- Image 1 -->
                                <li data-target="#quote-carousel" data-slide-to="1" onMouseOver="$('.carousel').carousel(0); $('.carousel').carousel('pause');" class="active"><img class="img-responsive" src="http://designs.josephr.mobi/test/c.png" alt="Name 1"></li>
                                <!-- Image 2 -->
                                <li data-target="#quote-carousel" data-slide-to="2" onMouseOver="$('.carousel').carousel(1); $('.carousel').carousel('pause');" ><img class="img-responsive" src="http://designs.josephr.mobi/test/c.png" alt="Name 2"></li>
                                <!-- Image 3 -->
                                <li data-target="#quote-carousel" data-slide-to="3" onMouseOver="$('.carousel').carousel(2); $('.carousel').carousel('pause');" ><img class="img-responsive" src="http://designs.josephr.mobi/test/c.png" alt="Name 3"></li>
                                <!-- Image 4 -->
                                <li data-target="#quote-carousel" data-slide-to="4" onMouseOver="$('.carousel').carousel(3); $('.carousel').carousel('pause');" ><img class="img-responsive" src="http://designs.josephr.mobi/test/c.png" alt="Name 4"></li>
                                <!-- Image 5 -->
                                <li data-target="#quote-carousel" data-slide-to="5" onMouseOver="$('.carousel').carousel(4); $('.carousel').carousel('pause');" ><img class="img-responsive" src="http://designs.josephr.mobi/test/c.png" alt="Name 5"></li>
                                <!-- Image 6 -->
                                <li data-target="#quote-carousel" data-slide-to="6" onMouseOver="$('.carousel').carousel(5); $('.carousel').carousel('pause');"  ><img class="img-responsive" src="http://designs.josephr.mobi/test/c.png" alt="Name 6"></li>
        <!-- Image 7 -->
                                <li data-target="#quote-carousel" data-slide-to="6" onMouseOver="$('.carousel').carousel(6); $('.carousel').carousel('pause');" ><img class="img-responsive" src="http://designs.josephr.mobi/test/c.png" alt="Name 7"></li>
                            </ol>   
                            
                            <!-- Carousel Buttons Next/Prev
                            <a data-slide="prev" href="#quote-carousel" class="left carousel-control"><i class="fa fa-chevron-left"></i></a>
                            <a data-slide="next" href="#quote-carousel" class="right carousel-control"><i class="fa fa-chevron-right"></i></a> -->
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
</div>

    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

</body>
</html>
```

What I need ?

- When clicking on current .active image I don't want the carousel to switch to the next image.

Comment: can you share some of your code so we will know what might be the problem instead of searching through the page

Comment: @jackjop just added the snippet

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is your li elements have attributes like

```
data-slide-to="1"
```

Instead of starting with 1, start them with zero so the clicks will work fine.

https://jsfiddle.net/yc7zcrtp/